# JAX-RS missing params (complex type) in request and response

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, wadl

I'm using JAX-RS to create a WADL file. The main problem is that when using a complex type (Ergebnis) in the generated WADL file the details of the request are missing. When i change the complex types Ergebnis and Anfrage in simple types like String the output is as expected. My code can be seen below.

I had to massively reduce my code to describe my problem concise. Hopefully i didn't mess up and type some mistakes in it. I hope someone can help me.

```
@POST
@Path("/testpfad")
@Produces(MT_JSON)
@Consumes(MT_JSON)
@Descriptions({ @Description(value = "Testbeschreibung", target = DocTarget.METHOD) })
Ergebnis testMethod(@NotNull Anfrage anfrage)

@XmlRootElement
@Doc(value = "Beschreibung")
public class Ergebnis {

    @Doc("Beschreibung")
    private boolean test

    public boolean isTest() {
        return test
    }

    public void setTest(final boolean test) {
        this.test = test
    }
}
```

Anfrage is looking similar to Ergebnis.

Generated WADL file:

```
<application>
    <grammars>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:element name="Anfrage" type="Anfrage"/>
            <xs:element name="Ergebnis" type="Ergebnis"/>
            <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="Anfrage">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="test" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="Ergebnis">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="test" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/test">
        <resource path="/">
            <resource path="testpfad">
                <method name="POST">
                    <doc>Beschreibung</doc>
                    <request>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </request>
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```